# Internationalize the attributes of an object

Tags: python, django, templates, internationalization, django-templates

My object has an attribute called status. Status can have two states: **opened** and **closed**. The value of this attribute should be translated. I've tried to do this in two ways:

```
<td> {% trans object.status %} </td>
```

and

```
<td>
    {% blocktrans with object.status as status %} {{ status }} {% endblocktrans %}
</td>
```

but with no result. In django.po file I have an entry %(status)s. How will Django know how to translate the status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If status can only have two states, you should use the `choices` attribute in the model definition. The values for choices can then be marked for translation:

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('open', _('open')),
    ('closed', _('closed'))
)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
```

and in the template, use the `get_status_display` method:

```
<td> {{ object.get_status_display }} </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

check if you drop these 4 lines into the po:

```
msgid "opend"
msgstr "Your translated word"

msgid "closed"
msgstr "your trans word"
```

and run :

```
manage.py compiletranslation
```

because when you edit the .po file with existing .mo file, the change have no effect